# Mapping an array to consecutive non-nil values of a method?

Tags: ruby

So, I have `x` variable names I want to assign to `x` consecutive non-`nil` values from a method… how can I do that?

For example, I want to map `%w[alpha beta gamma]` to the three consecutive non-`nil` values of the function `get(x)` beginning with 0.

So, say the values of `get(x)` are `get(0)=1`, `get(1)=54`, `get(2)=nil`, `get(3)=6`. I'd want `alpha = 1`, `beta = 54`, and `gamma = 6`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting Hash key/value pairs may not really answer the question but it's almost always the right solution for a real program ...

```
def get x # test sub
  [1, 54, nil, 6][x]
end

# find the next n non-nil values of an integer function
def find n, sofar, nextval
  return sofar if sofar.length >= n
  return find n, (sofar << get(nextval)).compact, nextval + 1
end

h = {}
h[:alpha], h[:beta], h[:gamma] = find 3, [], 0
p h
```